# ASP.Net Custom Control - Override "Text" Property

Tags: asp.net

This would seem to be very simple, but it's not working for me.  I desparately need to know how to override the "Text" property of a server control I created, which inherits from "Label".  When the control is dropped into an ASP Web form, I want the text property to already be set to a certain value.  I tried:

```
[Browsable(true), Bindable(true), Category("Behavior"), Localizable(true)]
[DefaultValue("00:00:00")]
public override string Text{get; set;}
```

But it doesnt work; the "Text" property shows up blank - and when I try to edit it, I can change it to anything *except* the value specified in the "DefaultValue" attrib.  This property is supposed to be overridable.

I also need to be able to set the "ID" property so it's set to a specific value when dropped on the form.  Is this possible?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is similar to or duplicate of: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657131/default-value-in-asp-net-server-control][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657131/default-value-in-asp-net-server-control

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you can use the [ToolBoxDataAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.toolboxdataattribute.aspx):

> Specifies the default tag generated for a custom control when it is
>   dragged from a toolbox in a tool such as Microsoft Visual Studio.
>
> By default, the visual designer of a tool such as Visual Studio,
>   creates an empty tag. This is a tag representing a control in its
>   default state, when the control is dropped from the toolbox of a
>   visual designer onto the design surface. To specify initial default
>   values, a control can make use of this attribute. You can use this
>   attribute to customize the initial HTML content that is placed in the
>   designer when the control is dragged from the toolbox onto the form.

It would look something like this for your control:

```
[ToolBoxData("<{0}:TimeLabel ID='TL1' Text='00:00:00' runat='server' />")]
public class TimeLabel : System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label
{
  [DefaultValue("00:00:00")]
  public override string Text
  {
    get { return ViewState["Text"] != null ? (string)ViewState["Text"] : "00:00:00"; }
    set { ViewState["Text"] = value; }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey @michielvoo (sry for associating your name to the wrong comment!).  Thx for the suggestion, it worked!  I reviewed the documentation and now (I think!) have a full understanding of all things "HTML generation" fromn a custom control.  Thx for steering me in right direction

Comment: Oh just a footnote; I also removed the "DefaultValue" attribure as it seemed extraneous.

Comment: @user1172173 The `[DefaultValue]` attribute is helpful for editors because it's used by Visual Studio in the properties window. Any value other than "00:00:00" will be highlighted in **bold** by Visual Studio.

Comment: Understood, thx @michielvoo.  Yeah after reviewing the doc on this attrib, kinda came to the same conclusion.  As a quick follow-up on my other question, was disheartened to learn that the attrib doesn't seem to work for the "ID" property; it still wants to create its own by using the control class name plus a sequence number

Comment: Sorry to clarify, I meant the class-level attribute "ToolBoxData" didn't seem to save the "ID" I supplied (created its own default)...

Comment: @user1172173 Ah yes, I can understand why it would do that. Visual Studio wants to prevent duplicate IDs most likely. PS. You can delete your comment on the other answer, no?

Answer (score 0):

The DefaultValue attribute is intended to display a default value in Properties Tab.
So when you launch website without specify a value for your Text property .net uses this one.
IMHO you have not chance to do that. Sorry!